# JAVA_HOME points to an invalid installation during ElasticSearch installation

Tags: elasticsearch, installation, elastic-stack, java-home

I'm trying to run the following command through powershell to install ElastiSearch but it the service batch file can't find the JAVA_HOME path.

I've added JAVA_HOME to my system variables and I can see the path when I echo JAVA_HOME through command line. Not sure why the batch file is pointing to an empty path.

> Invoke-Expression -command "C:\elasticsearch-6.5.4\elasticsearch-6.5.
>   4\bin\elasticsearch-service install"
>
> Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
>
> Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  ""
>
> JAVA_HOME points to an invalid Java installation (no jvm.dll found in "").
>
> Exiting...

Comment: Is it pointing to the correct path? Try to run `java -version` on the CMD and please add the result to your question.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? it seems that I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your variable in system variables JAVA_HOME is pointing to the wrong location. Make sure to provide the right path for JAVA_HOME to be: .\Java\jdk1.8.0